# Determine if there is a space in a cell in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a a spreadsheet with over 2000 lines that each have a unique reference number.  I want to use the reference numbers to VLOOKUP to another report.  my problem is that while all reference numbers have a letter at the end, some have a space between the letter and the numbers while others do not have a space in-between.

For example: 637408 A  compared to 837408A

The sheet I want to use a VLOOKUP to compare the references with does not have a space between the letter and the numbers.  Is there an Excel function that I can use to quickly detect which references have a space, and if they do, eliminate the space?  Thank You.

Comment: Look into substitute()

Comment: How would you use the substitute function for this purpose?  Or the global replace function?  I just tried both and neither seem to work.  Must be missing something

Comment: in a new column `=SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","")`

Comment: Where is the data coming from? It could be that the "spaces" aren't actually spaces (char 32), but instead some sort of unprintable character showing as a space (char 160 for example).

Comment: Perhaps use SUBSTITUTE in the VLOOKUP formula - is it the lookup value or the lookup range which is inconsistent?

Comment: Thanks Scott that is a big time saver for me.  It is the Vlookup range that is inconsistent Barry.  I am certain that they are spaces tiger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove all spaces in, say, column **A**, try this short macro:

```
Sub SpaceKiller()
    Range("A:A").Replace What:=" ", replacement:=""
End Sub
```